# how to set a link on magazine page with curl page in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to set a link to jump to a page number in iPhone or iPad magazine??I am using curl pages demo "jemmons-PageCurl-2d5017a" for a curl in ipad ..

What I want is when i click on page number then  it should go to  that page number of magazine i.e. I want to set link to it..

Thanks in Advance.